# Ubuntu Kylin Artful Aardvark (17.10)

Tags: 17.10, kylin

Hello my name is Tyler T. I'm wondering, when will "Ubuntu Kylin 17.10" be officially available to download? Please reply whenever you can, please and thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is already available. Please visit [official site - http://www.ubuntukylin.com](http://www.ubuntukylin.com/downloads/show.php?lang=en&id=122).